# applet button filling area

Tags: java, user-interface, button, applet

I'm creating an applet and having problems with the positioning as size of my buttons. I've added two buttons, but the "OK" button seems to position and size itself correctly, but the "CLEAR" button fills the entire applet area behind the "OK" button. Any suggestions as to what is the problem?

```
@Override
public void init() 
{
    super.init();

    setSize(J_WIDTH, J_HEIGHT);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    btn_OK = new Button("OK");
    btn_CLEAR = new Button("CLEAR");

    btn_OK.setBounds(50, 450, 75, 50);
    btn_CLEAR.setBounds(125, 50, 75, 50);

    add(btn_OK);
    add(btn_CLEAR);

    btn_OK.addActionListener(this);
    btn_CLEAR.addActionListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `BorderLayout`, you should specify a location where you want to place the component. If you don't, the default is `BorderLayout.CENTER`. Also, each position can only contain one component. So when you call `add(btn_OK)`, the OK button is added to the center of the panel. But then you replace it with the Clear button by calling `add(btn_CLEAR);`.

In addition, each position in the `BorderLayout` takes up a certain amount of space. The component at that position will stretch to fill that space. In particular, the CENTER takes up all remaining space not used by the other positions.

I think that `BorderLayout` is not what you want here. Check out the [Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information on each LayoutManager. You can also follow the rest of the tutorial trail for details about how to implement each of them.

You should also bookmark and familiarize yourself with [the Java API docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763827/applet-button-filling-area/14763905#14763905). These are an essential tool for every Java programmer and will help you answer many questions on your own.

Comment: (Actually, `BorderLayout` will only allow one component to occupy a given point within it's layout, basically zeroing out all other components, but the concept is the same)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the clarification. That is bad wording on my part. I wasn't sure if one component replaced the other or if they were simply drawn one on top of the other.

Comment: It's nit picky on my part, but your concept was correct +1 by the way

Comment: Thanks for the input. Decided to make the layout null for better control of positioning

Comment: @SpicyWeenie Null layouts are frowned upon by most Java programmers. This is mostly because you will have to recalculate positions and sizes by hand when the user resizes the window. LayoutManagers do this work for you. I strongly suggest that you learn about the different layouts which are available. There is almost certainly one which will give you the look you want.

Comment: Yeah, I already understood resizing issues, but my applet doesn't require resizing since it will be quite small.